# Crash occured when parsing datetime dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt (having dynamic input)

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I have my code here which parses a `String` to `DateTime`.

```
DateTime datenew = DateTime.Parse("05/06/2015 17:18:12");
String convertDate = datenew .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

This parse is automatically converting the time `16:13:12` to `05:18:12 PM`.
This is working smoothly until I entered a format of dd/MM/yyyy *(BTW this is regardless of hh:mm:ss tt or hh:mm:ss only. It does not matter)*. It throws an exception.

For example I input `18/02/2015 17:18:12`, now it throws an error.

I want my input to be dynamic, regardless of `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` format. I just want a standard output in `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format.

Any suggestions?

Edit.

```
Exception thrown: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message it's throwing?

Comment: As @GrantWinney points out, writing code that tries to guess what format a date is is almost always a bad idea. Pick a required format and stick with it.

Comment: @DmitryK. Please see edited post :)

Comment: @GrantWinney - It happened when I changed the input to 18/02/2015 17:18:12 but the 05/06/2015 17:18:12 works fine. The problem is when I input 18/02/2015 17:18:12.

Comment: @Rob - BTW this is just a replication of my code. THere is an argument supplying on the parsing of date. :)

Comment: @WhiteMark Yes, 05/06 'works fine', but it's still potentially wrong. Whoever is supplying the '18/02/2015' format clearly uses 'dd/MM/yyyy' - which means, if *they* sent you '05/06/2015', they would mean 5th June, but you would read it as 6th May.

Comment: @Rob Yes you are right. Now thats another problem. LOL. Do you have any ideas on how can I handle this?

Comment: @WhiteMark The only way to handle it is to have a flag indicating which format the date will be in. Depending on how you're getting this information, that flag could be set on a client row, based on the file name, url, user, etc. That parts up to you. Other than that, you could choose a specific format that you require, and force all inputs to use it.

Comment: @Rob I do totally get what you are saying. But can you show me some snippet on how to do this? Having a hard time. I have a specific format that I require and I want all the input to use it regardless of MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, you need to determine the format of the date before you try to parse it. Where you define this format is up to you.

```
void Main()
{
    var format = GetFormat();
    var input = "05/06/2015 17:18:12";
    var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var output = parsedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
}

string GetFormat()
{
    //Take this from their user, client, file name, etc, etc.
    //Where this is configured doesn't really matter - but it needs to be somewhere.

    if (client.IsAmerican)
    {
        return "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    } else {
        return "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I get you now. I think were on the same side now. But how can I handle this If i got an input of 05/06/2015 05:18:12 PM already?

Comment: @WhiteMark That is fine, as long as you know the format the sender is using. If you don't know the format, it's impossible to know what date it is. You can only guess.

Comment: So there is a possibility that my program will crash if caught another dateformat? Ugh! Hehe! Thanks for this ROB! Helps alot.

Comment: @WhiteMark No worries! And yes - it will crash if they use a different format, though in my opinion it's better to fail on bad data rather than accept it (and have it be wrong) silently:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and guess it's not working because it doesn't know what format the date is supposed to be in.

Look at the first two examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Parse2_Example) that explain how to set the culture or style.

Comment: I think the DateTime.Parse only accepts the MM/dd/yyyy format? IDK how to use this if the input is dd/MM/yyyy. Because I need to parse the datetoString with the custom format. Any ideas?